# Fetch users from USR02 based on validity date - SAP ABAP

Tags: abap

I am working on SAP Report, wherein I am fetching user data from the USR02 Table, My requirement is I want to display users based on

1. User name
2. User Type: These two are working Fine
3. Valid from - (Date)
4. Valid To - (Date)

In Valid from - (Date) & Valid To - (Date) only those users should be displayed who are valid on the specified date (Parameter/ Select Options anything will do)

For Eg: A user is valid from 01/01/2020 to 31/12/2021
And when I insert a date 12/03/2021, User info should be displayed,
But I am getting an inappropriate output:
When I enter the exact valid date i.e 01/01/2020 then output comes as desired,
But when I enter the date as of 12/03/2021 or any date between 01/01/2020 to 31/12/2021, no data comes

Here's the code which I tried :

```
'''
REPORT Report_name

TABLES: USR02.

TYPE-POOLS: SLIS.

DATA: FIELDCATALOG TYPE SLIS_T_FIELDCAT_ALV WITH HEADER LINE,

* GD_LAYOUT TYPE SLIS_LAYOUT_ALV,

GD_REPID LIKE SY-REPID.

TYPES: BEGIN OF ITAB,

BNAME TYPE USR02-BNAME,

GLTGV TYPE USR02-GLTGV,

GLTGB TYPE USR02-GLTGB,

USTYP TYPE USR02-USTYP,

END OF ITAB.

SELECTION-SCREEN: BEGIN OF BLOCK one WITH FRAME TITLE TEXT-001.

SELECT-OPTIONS: s_BNAME for USR02-BNAME,

s_GLTGV for USR02-GLTGV NO-EXTENSION NO INTERVALS,

* s_GLTGB for USR02-GLTGB DEFAULT '1500000000' TO '1599999999' ,

* s_GLTGV for USR02-GLTGV NO-EXTENSION NO INTERVALS,

s_GLTGB for USR02-GLTGB NO-EXTENSION NO INTERVALS,

s_USTYP for USR02-USTYP NO-EXTENSION NO INTERVALS.

DATA: wa_na TYPE ITAB,

it_na TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ITAB.

select BNAME GLTGV GLTGB USTYP FROM USR02 INTO TABLE it_na

WHERE BNAME in s_BNAME and

GLTGV in s_GLTGV and

* GLTGV <='2021-04-11' and

GLTGB in s_GLTGB and

* GLTGV BETWEEN s_GLTGV AND s_GLTGB.

USTYP in s_USTYP.

SELECTION-SCREEN: End of BLOCK one.

FIELDCATALOG-FIELDNAME = 'BNAME'.

FIELDCATALOG-SELTEXT_M = 'USER NAME'.

FIELDCATALOG-COL_POS = 0.

APPEND FIELDCATALOG TO FIELDCATALOG.

CLEAR FIELDCATALOG.

FIELDCATALOG-FIELDNAME = 'GLTGV'.

FIELDCATALOG-SELTEXT_M = 'VALID FROM'.

FIELDCATALOG-COL_POS = 1.

APPEND FIELDCATALOG TO FIELDCATALOG.

CLEAR FIELDCATALOG.

FIELDCATALOG-FIELDNAME = 'GLTGB'.

FIELDCATALOG-SELTEXT_M = 'VALID TO'.

FIELDCATALOG-COL_POS = 2.

APPEND FIELDCATALOG TO FIELDCATALOG.

CLEAR FIELDCATALOG.

FIELDCATALOG-FIELDNAME = 'USTYP'.

FIELDCATALOG-SELTEXT_M = 'USER TYPE'.

FIELDCATALOG-COL_POS = 3.

APPEND FIELDCATALOG TO FIELDCATALOG.

CLEAR FIELDCATALOG.

GD_REPID = SY-REPID.

CALL FUNCTION 'REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY'

EXPORTING

I_CALLBACK_PROGRAM = GD_REPID

* I_CALLBACK_TOP_OF_PAGE = 'TOP-OF-PAGE' "see FORM

* I_CALLBACK_USER_COMMAND = 'USER_COMMAND'

IT_FIELDCAT = FIELDCATALOG[]

I_SAVE = 'X'

* IS_VARIANT = G_VARIANT

TABLES

T_OUTTAB = it_na

EXCEPTIONS

PROGRAM_ERROR = 1

OTHERS = 2.

IF SY-SUBRC <> 0.

* MESSAGE ID SY-MSGID TYPE SY-MSGTY NUMBER SY-MSGNO

* WITH SY-MSGV1 SY-MSGV2 SY-MSGV3 SY-MSGV4.

ENDIF.

'''
```

Your comments will help
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Also asked in SAP Community at https://answers.sap.com/questions/13554711/fetch-users-from-usr02-based-on-validity-date.html (one existing answer)

Comment: you cannot check user validity via comparing fields separately like `GLTGB in s_GLTGB`, you should check both boundaries via BETWEEN. And also Sebastian is correct, this way you will discard users with empty validity fields, which are always valid, you should use `UNION` for that or set of `OR` conditions

Answer (score 1):

You need check fields GLTGB and GLTGV. Those fields must be empty.

```
    TYPES: BEGIN OF lty_usr02,
         bname TYPE usr02-bname,
         gltgv TYPE usr02-gltgv,
         gltgb TYPE usr02-gltgb,
         uflag TYPE usr02-uflag,
       END OF lty_usr02.

DATA: ls_usr02 TYPE lty_usr02.

SELECT SINGLE bname
              gltgv
              gltgb
              uflag
FROM usr02
INTO ls_usr02
WHERE bname EQ user.

IF sy-subrc NE 0.

  RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE cx_t100_msg
    EXPORTING
      t100_msgid = 'B0'
      t100_msgno = '282'
      t100_msgv1 = CONV string( user ).

ENDIF.

IF ls_usr02-uflag NE 0.

  RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE cx_t100_msg
    EXPORTING
      t100_msgid = '01'
      t100_msgno = '542'
      t100_msgv1 = CONV string( user ).

ENDIF.

IF  ls_usr02-gltgv IS NOT INITIAL
AND ls_usr02-gltgb IS NOT INITIAL
AND sy-datum NOT BETWEEN ls_usr02-gltgv AND ls_usr02-gltgb.

  RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE cx_t100_msg
    EXPORTING
      t100_msgid = 'OSPCT_MSG'
      t100_msgno = '050'
      t100_msgv1 = CONV string( user ).

ENDIF.
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that it does not work is that both date conditions must be met. In the case with the interval: `GLTGV` might be equal to 01/01/2020, but if `GLTGB` is not equal to 31/12/2021, then it will not be selected. Try using a single date parameter:

```
PARAMETERS: p_date TYPE sy-datum.
```

And use following select statement:

```
SELECT BNAME GLTGV GLTGB USTYP 
FROM USR02 
INTO TABLE it_na
WHERE BNAME in s_BNAME and
GLTGV <= p_date and
GLTGB >= p_date and
USTYP in s_USTYP.
```